# JSON and Soundcloud

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, json, soundcloud

I'm using a cocoa wrapper API to post audio tracks from my iPhone app to Soundcloud. I have some basic functionality working, but I'm not sure where I am supposed input keys that Soundcloud gave me. Here is a clipped photo from my developer's page:

[image]

which I believe is supposed to be somehow plugged in here:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What Soundcloud gave you is OAuth2 keys, while the code you're showing is good old plain OAuth.

Comment: Right. Any idea where I plug in the OAuth2 stuff?

Comment: Where is this source code comes from? There's probably a version made for OAuth2 with a different logic somewhere.

Comment: Here is the source code. But I can't seem to find where to plug it in. Maybe I just need to search harder :) https://github.com/soundcloud/cocoa-api-wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289993/how-to-use-oauth-properly).